# Probably wrong statement about Faraday's Law in my homework question's answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, textbook-erratum

[image]

***A very long solenoid*** has circular cross section with $R=10 cm $ radius. The wire wound around the solenoid has winding density $n=10^6$ $wires/meter$. The current in the wire is flowing in the counter-clockwise direction and increases at a constant rate of $\frac{dI}{dt}=0.25 A/s$

***Question:***
Find the electric field $\vec E_Q$ at the point $Q$, which is on the $x$ axis and has a radial
distance of $r_Q = 20 cm$  from the central axis.

In answer $\dfrac{d\phi_B}{dt}$ is found not zero. Since it is very solenoid there will be no magnetic field outside the solenoid so $\dfrac{dB}{dt}$ ***must be zero. Is it true?***

***If it is not zero, then how? How zero magnetic field value has non zero derivative?***

Comment: Indeed, $dB/dt$ at the point $Q$ is zero. That doesn't mean $\Phi_B$ is zero, because $\Phi_B$ contains the flux that goes through a whole surface, which contains regions with nonzero field.

Comment: @knzhou That seems like an answer rather than a comment.